# How to properly get the content of the variable is JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need alert the content of a `text` in JavaScript Eg. **Noodles: yes. Rice: No. Beans: No. Milk: Yes.**

But the code below only alerts **"Noodles**

```
var str ='{"value": "{\"text\":\" Noodles: yes. Rice: No. Beans: No. Milk: Yes.\"}" }';
var content = str.split(':')[2];
alert(content);
```

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: Where do you get that data from? Looks like it was originally some JSON encode data, where `value` itself also held some JSON encoded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the current scenario, you could do this. It's dirty but will get the job done

```js
var str ='{"value": "{\"text\":\" Noodles: yes. Rice: No. Beans: No. Milk: Yes.\"}" }';
const jsonParsed = JSON.parse( str.replace(`"{"`, `{"`).replace(`}"`, `}`) )
alert(jsonParsed.value.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not in proper JSON format, it cannot be directly converted to a JSON object, so string manipulation is required. Of course it is not the best method but you can try a solution like this. I got each element after index 2, removed unnecessary characters, then joined them by joining with ":"

```
var str ='{"value": "{\"text\":\" Noodles: yes. Rice: No. Beans: No. Milk: Yes.\"}" }';
var content = str.split(':').slice(2).map(item=>{
    return item.replace(/['"}]+/g, '')
})
alert(content);
```